# Manage a return's promise from BluethoothSerial ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm wrinting a code that checks just if Bluethooth connection is enable or not . So I did this :

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/bluetooth-serial
```

Into my construct i have this :

```
construnct(....
  private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial,
  .....){..
```

Now here

```
construnct(....
  private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial,
  .....){..
this.bluetoothSerial.isEnabled(/*here*/);
 ...}
```

I need to menage if bluethooth's enable or no?

I create a boolean variable and I want to assign it true or false, that depens it bluethooth is enable or not. But how to do it?

The ref :

```
bluetoothSerial.isEnabled(
    function() {
        console.log("Bluetooth is enabled");
        //myboolflag=true; dosen't work!!!
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Bluetooth is *not* enabled");
    }
);
```

[here](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial#isenabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arrow functions like this:

```
bluetoothSerial.isEnabled(
    () => {
        console.log("Bluetooth is enabled");
        this.myboolflag = true; // Should work now!!!
    },
    () => {
        console.log("Bluetooth is *not* enabled");
    }
);
```

By using arrow functions, the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance.

Comment: It gives me this error **Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.**

Comment: Does it give you more details? Or how should the `isEnabled` method be called?

Comment: Man I had this error : - inline template:0:43 caused by: No provider for BluetoothSerial!

Comment: Please try by including BluetoothSerial in the providers array from your NgModule

Comment: I did it : **providers: [........,  BluetoothSerial,..........]** , in appModule.ts